# Swagger issue with Autofac

Tags: asp.net-web-api, autofac, swagger

I'm struggling with an issue due Autofac and Swagger. When I try to reach the Swagger UI I have this exception:

> 500 : {  "message": "An error has occurred.",  "exceptionMessage":
>   "None of the constructors found with
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
>   'MRV.EntregaChaves.PEC.Api.Areas.HelpPage.XmlDocumentationProvider'
>   can be invoked with the available services and parameters:\r\nCannot
>   resolve parameter 'System.String documentPath' of constructor 'Void
>   .ctor(System.String)'.",  "exceptionType":
>   "Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException",  "stackTrace": " at
>   Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)\r\n at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()\r\n
>   at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n at
>   Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n at
>   Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n at
>   Autofac.Core.Container.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n at
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext
>   context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object&
>   instance)\r\n at
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext
>   context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n at
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext
>   context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)\r\n at
>   Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext
>   context, Type serviceType)\r\n at
>   Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyScope.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)\r\n at
>   Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Services.DefaultServices.GetService(Type
>   serviceType)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.ServicesExtensions.GetService[TService](ServicesContainer
>   services)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.ServicesExtensions.GetDocumentationProvider(ServicesContainer
>   services)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Description.ApiExplorer.GetApiDocumentation(HttpActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Description.ApiExplorer.PopulateActionDescriptions(HttpActionDescriptor
>   actionDescriptor, IHttpRoute route, String localPath, Collection`1
>   apiDescriptions)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Description.ApiExplorer.ExploreDirectRoute(HttpControllerDescriptor
>   controllerDescriptor, CandidateAction[] candidates, IHttpRoute
>   route)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Description.ApiExplorer.InitializeApiDescriptions()\r\n
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous
>   location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value()\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Description.ApiExplorer.get_ApiDescriptions()\r\n at
>   Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.GetApiDescriptionsFor(String
>   apiVersion)\r\n at
>   Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String rootUrl, String
>   apiVersion)\r\n at
>   Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerDocsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at
>   System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<>n__FabricatedMethod9(HttpRequestMessage ,
>   CancellationToken )\r\n at
>   System.Web.Http.HttpServer.d__0.MoveNext()"  }
>   http://localhost:18184/swagger/docs/v1

Comment: You should post the code you're struggling with.

Comment: There's no code! I just intalled the nuget package and It has done the self-config.

Comment: Post the self-config code. It's impossible to help if it's not possible to reproduce the error. Or at least tell us which NuGet packages and versions to download, to be able to reproduce this exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue fallowing the official github respository [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle).

The problem was due OWIN. I miss installed the package `Swashbuckle.Core`.